# Reject a OS X system shutdown

Tags: java, macos, swt

We have an SWT application which causes to hang when it is still running and the user triggers a system shutdown on OS X. Closing the application from the application menu works fine.

I've tried to register a `SWT.Close` listener to the `Display` instance:

```
display.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (!handleExitRequest()) {
            event.doit = false;
            event.type = SWT.None;
        }
    }
});
```

This solves magically the hang, but unfortunately, it is not reliable called when exiting. :(

Comment: Have you tried to cleanup and close the SWT stuff with a [Shutdown Hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))?

Comment: No. IIRC, the shutdown hook will be triggered when the VM is exiting, but my VM just hangs.

Comment: Can you explain with a few words "the magic"? What does this line check: `if (!handleExitRequest())`? I'd like to see the full method.

Comment: `handleExitRequest` is a method in our code which returns `true` if the application can exit directly (e.g. no unsaved changes). If it can't exit right now, it returns `false`. I assumed this as obvious.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, how? It would be good if you would post an answer. To inform us about the issues of SWT on Macs...

Comment: I don't know why, but this event listener seems to be called now more reliable than two weeks ago. Very strange.

Comment: Alright then, I'll delete my answer soon, if there's no upvote...I anyway forgot something to suggest: OS/X reinstallation. :/

Answer (score 1):

I have had mixed results listening for shutdown hooks on the main thread.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. What has worked for me in the past is to create a separate thread and register the shutdown hook to that.

```
public class MyGuiApplication
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Thread shutdownThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            // Put graceful shutdown code of the main application/thread here.
          }
        });

        runtime.addShutdownHook( shutdownThread );

        startMyApp();
    }
}
```

Hopefully that might work for you.

Comment: I'm not asking about a shutdown hook. I'm asking for get a notification if the system is going to shut-down, so my application can exit cleanly or reject the shutdown, e.g. when there are unsaved changes.

Comment: There is no way within Java that I know for you to actually reject an operating system shutdown.  Also, you did not indicate clearly indicate what your goal was in the original question asked.  If you want better answers, you might want to edit your question and indicate exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use this approach rather than trying to work around things the way you are?  Seems better to not hang and close properly rather than block the user's requested action (shutdown). ??

Comment: Is not the shutdown hook the way to get the notification you are seeking? Couldn't your shutdown hook call the code you are calling from the Display.Close above?  sorry if that's off base. I don't do SWT apps.

Comment: IMHO the shutdownhook is invoked if `System.exit` is invoked. There is no possbility to abort this VM shutdown! This is useful to cleanup resources. But this is not the problem here.

Comment: Ah, I see your note above about wanting to prompt for unsaved changes. ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/Application.html) and this [class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/JavaSE6_AppleExtensionsRef/api/com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler.html).

> The Application class allows you to integrate your Java application with the native OS X environment.
>   ...
>   Cancel shutdown/logout if the user has unsaved changes in your application.

You can take a look at following questions too:

[How to cancel shutdown in Mac OS X when application is an agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344980/how-to-cancel-shutdown-in-mac-os-x-when-application-is-an-agent)